# convert more arrays into single array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Convert these array into one array

```
Array ( [0] => 10 )
Array ( [0] => 17 )
Array ( [0] => 17 )
Array ( [0] => 15 )
```

I want an output like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 10 ,[1] => 17,[2] => 17,[3] => 15)
```

Comment: `array_merge()`.go for that

Comment: inside foreach loop i am getting $x = Array ( [0] => 10 ),each time,17,17,15 value

Comment: i convert these into array an used array_merge.but it returns same array

Comment: Is the first output from inside a loop?

Comment: This question is unclear.  Please show us the code that is creating these arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a=array(10);$b=array(17);$c=array(17);$d=array(15);

print_r(array_merge($a,$b,$c,$d));

//Array([0]=>10 [1]=>17 [2]=>17 [3]=>15)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming that your Main Array contains some sub-arrays nested within it like so:

```
<?php
    $arrNestedArray = array(
        array(10),
        array(17),
        array(17),
        array(15),
        array("data"=>array("fName"=>"Cosmic", "lName"=>"Joy")),
    );
```

> And, now; you want to take-out all the values of every element in the sub-arrays and turn them into direct elements of the Main Array. You can do that with array_walk... and then build up your Flat Array having the Structure you had anticipated like this:

```
<?php
    // CREATE AN EMPTY ARRAY TO HOLD THE FINAL RESULT YOU DESIRED...
    $singleArray    = array();

    // THIS IS A SAMPLE OF THE MAIN ARRAY CONTAINING SUB ARRAYS...
    $arrNestedArray = array(
        array(10),
        array(17),
        array(17),
        array(15),
        array("data"=>array("fName"=>"Cosmic", "lName"=>"Joy")),
    );

    array_walk($arrNestedArray, function($data, $index) use(&$singleArray) {
        if( is_array($data) ) {
            foreach ($data as $key=>$item) {
                if(!in_array($item, $singleArray)) {
                    if(is_array($item)) {
                        $singleArray[$key]   = $item;
                    }else{
                        $singleArray[$index] = $item;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    var_dump($singleArray);
```

> Finally, while you might still want to [test it out here](https://eval.in/611420); the var_dump above produces something like this:

```
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 10
      1 => int 17
      3 => int 15
      'data' => 
        array (size=2)
          'fName' => string 'Cosmic' (length=6)
          'lName' => string 'Joy' (length=3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `array_merge` with `call_user_func_array`:

```
$a = array(Array ( 0 => 10 ), Array ( 0 => 17 ), Array ( 0 => 17 ), Array ( 0 => 15 ));
$ra = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $a);
print_r($ra); // Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 17 [2] => 17 [3] => 15 )
```