# Getting array values of inner array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(Bas\WWW\Router\Route\URIs\URI\Parameters\Parameter\Parameter)#13 (2) {
      ["name":"Bas\WWW\Router\Route\URIs\URI\Parameters\Parameter\Parameter":private]=>
      string(2) "name1"
      ["value":"Bas\WWW\Router\Route\URIs\URI\Parameters\Parameter\Parameter":private]=>
      string(2) "30"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Bas\WWW\Router\Route\URIs\URI\Parameters\Parameter\Parameter)#12 (2) {
      ["name":"Bas\WWW\Router\Route\URIs\URI\Parameters\Parameter\Parameter":private]=>
      string(2) "name2"
      ["value":"Bas\WWW\Router\Route\URIs\URI\Parameters\Parameter\Parameter":private]=>
      string(6) "289213"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Bas\WWW\Router\Route\URIs\URI\Parameters\Parameter\Parameter)#15 (2) {
      ["name":"Bas\WWW\Router\Route\URIs\URI\Parameters\Parameter\Parameter":private]=>
      string(6) "name3"
      ["value":"Bas\WWW\Router\Route\URIs\URI\Parameters\Parameter\Parameter":private]=>
      string(5) "00123"
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to retrieve all objects in it, which are the values of the inner array keys.

My approach was by looping the first outer values, then looping the inner values and placing those in a seperate array.

```
$a = [];
foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
    foreach ($parameter as $data) {
        $a[] = $data;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way for doing this instead of looping both of the arrays?

Comment: Is all you really want to do is to flatten your two dimensional array into a one dimensional array that you can iterate over?

Comment: @JeffLambert It's not something with high priority, but i was just wondering yeah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution is merge your sub_arrays, treating your array as a list of arguments to `array_merge`:

```
$a = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $parameters);
```

Comment: Are you saying inside the loop or just outside of it?

Comment: It's __instead__ of loop

Comment: It's hard to understand, but way much cleaner, thanks for this!

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38561163 ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution using `array_walk_recursive` function:

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($parameters, function($v) use(&$result){ $result[] = $v; });
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php